# Select rows from a table where a timestamp has not been made since the past 60 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, timestamp

I'm working on a project in sql managment studio with a sql server 2012 and I would like to get a list with user numbers whom hasn't made a transaction in the last 60 days. The data is from 2 tables (user and transaction) where one table hold the user number and user id and the other table holds the transaction timestamp and user id. The solutions i have right now is:

```sql
SELECT a.usernumber
FROM [user] a left join [transaction] b on a.id = b.user_id 
WHERE b.timestamp <= (SELECT getdate()-60) and a.usernumber is not null
```

The problem is that now it will return all users whom made a transaction more than 60 days ago, but they can also have made a transaction in the last 60 days. So what is a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your results by `usernumber`, calculate `max(b.timestamp)` and select only records having latest timestamp before your needed date:

```
select a.usernumber
from [user] a 
    left join [transaction] b on a.id = b.user_id 
where a.usernumber is not null
group by a.usernumber
having max(b.timestamp) <= (SELECT getdate()-60)
```

Comment: Would this method also apply if i wanted users with a transaction in the last 30 days?

having max(b.timestamp) **>=** (SELECT getdate()-30)?

Comment: @Glews yes, just pick any date offset you need

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to prefix `getdate()` call with `select`. But it's better to compute arguments which don't depend on every row before `select` statement. Your goal may be defined with other words: *Show me users for whom there is no transaction newer than 60 days old.*

Let's translate it to sql statements straightforward:

```
declare @oldestdate datetime

set @oldestdate = dateadd(dd, -60, getdate())

select u.username
from [user] u
where not exists
  (
    select 1 
    from [transaction] t
    where t.user_id = u.user_id
      and t.timestamp > @oldestdate
  )
```